# pyqtdeploy won't create project file

Tags: android, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtdeploy

I have been trying to use pyqtdeploy to port a Python program to Android, but can't seem to make it work.

I am using Python 3.7.5 and I have installed pyqtdeploy through pip install.

I have launched the command:

```
pyqtdeploy myproject.pyd
```

But it does not do anything (no file is created and the GUI does not start) and I get no error.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Download first your `pyqt-demo` folder that contains `.pdt` files (formerly `.pdy`), some `.py` files, a `systemroot` and a `data` folder.
[image]


You cannot create your own `.pdt` file, e.g. `pyqtdeploy myproj.pdt` but instead, you should really run `pyqtdeploy pyqt-demo.pdt` where `pyqt-demo.pdt` is the only file that will work. You are not creating a file, you are actually opening the file to start the GUI and modify it afterwards. You can check more about this here
https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/pyqtdeploy/index.html